# Set node status as Unpublished by programmatically in REST API

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-9

I am trying to set the node status as unpublished using the below code in ResourseBase custom Rest API but no luck.

Added the source code in below

```
namespace Drupal\custom_module_nam\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\rest\ModifiedResourceResponse;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "unpublish_node",
 *   label = @Translation("Unpublish node using webservice"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "create" = "/services/rest/unpublish"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class UnPublish extends ResourceBase {

  protected $entityTypeManager;  
  protected $entity;
  protected $entityStorage;
  

  public function __construct(
    array $configuration,
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entityTypeManager;
    $this->entityStorage = $entityTypeManager->getStorage('node');
  }


  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }


  public function post($value) {
      $entityArray = $this->entityStorage->loadByProperties(['field_name' => $value]);
      $this->entity = reset($entityArray);
      $this->entity->set('status', 0);
      $this->entity->save(); 
  }
}
```

Drupal Version is 9.5.1 and I need to unpublish the node in REST api call.

Comment: `$entity->set('status', 0)->save();` looks good :)

Comment: @johnSmith, but it still saving as published.

Comment: maybe you have some interfering modules like workflow oder content_moderation?, What is the highest class interface of entity? is it a NodeInterface?

Comment: Hi @johnSmith, added the source code in above, kindly check.

Comment: hmn the code looks good to me, did u debug it and check if $this->entity actually contains the node you expect? Did you check your watchdog messages for any hints? I would try if it works with `$node = reset($entityArray); ... $node->save();` even though i dont know  why it wouldnt work setting it to class property

Answer (score 0):

I erroneously updated the revision status as true in another function, but I have corrected it to false.

```
$revision = $this->entityStorage->createRevision($this->entity);
$revision->setRevisionLogMessage($message);
$revision->status = FALSE;
```